# How can I fix the "Property 'allowUndeclaredRTE' does not exist" error when using my Eclipse Checkstyle plugin?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, checkstyle

This is my error log:

> Checkstyle-Plugin: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - cannot initialize module JavadocMethod - Property 'allowUndeclaredRTE' does not exist, please check the documentation

Apparently, the “allowUndeclaredRTE" is the key here. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Support for `allowUndeclaredRTE` ended in Checkstyle v8.24. Your XML should work if you use a version prior to v8.24.

Comment: `allowUndeclaredRTE` seems to have been removed in v8.28  "Remove properties related to class loading from JavadocMethod." https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/releasenotes.html#Release_8.28

Answer (score 3):

Go to your **XML configuration** file that you are using and **remove or comment out the properties** that are invalid and then re-import it. Like this:

[image: Commented out invalid config]

Comment: It works!!Thank you, I just removed it and it ran again